# Python Binary Search (Maximum number of iterations)

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I was googling binary search in python and I found this:
http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/list_algorithms.html

It said that the general relationship between the max. numbers of iterations (same as Probe right?) and N (size of list) is given by `N = 2^k -1`,  where k is the max number of iterations .

However from my understanding, shouldn't the general relationship be `N = 2^k`
As each time after a search, we would divide out list by 2, until we get to 1.

Therefore the maximum number of iterations is `log2 N` instead of `log2 (N+1)`

I have googled this and I found one website support my answer but without much explanation. 
(link here: http://codingexplained.com/coding/theory/binary-search-algorithm)

Could someone explains the math behind it? Thanks.

Comment: "each time after a search, we would divide out list by 2, until we get to 1". No: in the implementation you reference, each iteration *removes one element of the list from consideration* and then reduces the region of interest to everything either to the right or the left of that element. And for concreteness, you should think of a "probe" as a list lookup (`xs[mid_index]`), rather than an iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Let `P(n)` be the number of probes needed for `n` elements. Then we can write the following equation:

```
P(0) = 0
P(n) = 1 + P((n-1)/2)
```

Explanation:
First we have no elements - nothing to do.
Then we do 1 probe and we're left with `(n-1)/2` elements (we throw 1 away because we just checked it) so we need to do `P((n-1)/2)` more.

The result for `P(n)` from this equation will be `floor(lg(n+1))`. You can check it on some examples (like n=6 and n=7) or you can read on how to solve recursive equations

Comment: The second equation should really be `P(n) = 1 + P(n // 2)`: consider the case `n = 6`, for example - we choose a 'middle' element, leaving 2 elements to one side and 3 to the other; in the worst case, we end up reducing to those 3 elements, so we want the equation to end up as `P(6) = 1 + P(3)`. (The first case where it makes a difference is `n = 2`; we should have `P(2) = 2`.)

Comment: I think you're right, but that will give a different result. Perhaps there really is a mistake in the article?

Comment: I don't think there's a mistake in the article. With `1 + P((n-1)/2)`, you get something that *disagrees* with what's in the article, as I already pointed out for `P(2)`. (For `P(2)`, you should get `ceil(log2(3))`, which is `2`, but with your definition you get `P(2) = 1`.) If you change the `(n-1)/2` to `n//2`, then your definition agrees with the article. Which part of the article do you think is mistaken?

Comment: Thanks both of you. I am trying to solve the recursive equation`P(n) = 1 + P(n/2)` but I somehow get a different solution. I substitute n by 2^n and eventually I got `P(n) = log2(n) + 1` . Although the difference is not much but I do appreciate if someone could tell me how to solve it . Thanks.